# Error for plugin tag in POM.xml while converting project to the maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, eclipse-plugin

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)

Getting above error while converting project to the MAVEN.

Comment: What exactly have you done to convert the project to Maven?

Comment: What was the command that you used?? I beleive it is wrong! Please post in more detail so that people can help you.. Like what command you used, a detail error description.. What are you tryuing to do.. etc